# Is there an auto complete in Sublime Text 2 when integrating it with SASS?

Tags: autocomplete, sass, sublimetext2

I've noticed that it does auto completes CSS properties and values, but not the case with SCSS.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`sass-textmate-bundle`](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle) port for ST2. According to the readme,

> This add-on adds syntax highlighting and tab/code completion for Sass and SCSS files. It features Zen Coding shortcuts for many CSS properties, making you look like some kind of stylesheet wizard to everyone around you. You've got to like that.

You might also want to take a look at [`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel/). While not specifically for SASS/SCSS, it features context-sensitive autocomplete based on what you've already typed in the file, so it may be useful on top of what ST2 already provides.

Both of these are available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).